# Club class of inaccessibles

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I am currently looking at what Drake calls the Axiom Schema F, "Every normal function defined for all ordinals has a regular fixed point".

In ZFC+(Axiom F), does it hold that there is a club class of inaccessibles?
It clear to me that they are unbounded, but I fail to see whether it's necessarily closed. Given a sequence of (0-)inaccessibles, if there is a limit, is it always regular (thus 1-inaccessible)?

For context: it seems to me that this would be a more elegant way to prove second part of Theorem 4.1 in ch.4 in Drake's *Set Theory, An Introduction to Large Cardinals*. Since $R_0$ (standard Levy's reflection) implies that given formula $\varphi$, there is a club class of $\alpha$s such that $\varphi \iff \varphi^{V_\alpha}$. If what I'm saying above holds, there would easily be a club class of inaccessible $\alpha$s satisfying the same property. But the same proof is very technical in both Levy's *Axiom Schemata of Strong Infinity* and Drake.

Comment: A limit of $\omega$ inaccessibles is not regular.

Comment: ok, that was fast, thank you.

Comment: Note however that ever the class of inaccessibles in this setting is 'class stationary' - by which I mean the following meta-theorem: Given any formula $\phi$ and parameters $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ such that $C := \{ \alpha \in \operatorname{Ord} \mid \phi(\alpha, p_{1}, \ldots, p_{n}) \}$ is a class club, there is some inaccessible $\kappa \in C$. (Just note that the monotone enumeration $F$ of $C$ is a class function and if $\kappa$ is an $F$-fixpoint, then $F(\kappa) = \kappa \in C$ is the $\kappa$-th element in $C$.)

Comment: I've noticed that since there is a club of ordinals satisfying reflection for a given formula $\varphi$, there is a normal function $f$ that enumerates them, limits of this function also form a club set, so they can be enumerated by a normal function $g$, which in turn has a regular fixed point due to F. Unless I've missed something important, this seems to be a an elegant way to prove what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, due to a simple reason: Let $C$ be a club class and let $\mu$ be any infinite cardinal (e.g. $\mu = \omega$). Then there is some $\kappa \in C$ such that $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa) = \operatorname{cf}(\mu)$.

Proof. Recursively construct a sequence $(\kappa_{i} \mid i \le \mu)$ be fixing any $\kappa_{0} \in C$, further letting $\kappa_{\alpha+1} := \min C \setminus \{ \kappa_{i} \mid i \le \alpha\}$ for successor ordinals $\alpha+1 \le \mu$ and finally, by letting $\kappa_{\lambda} := \sup \{ \kappa_{i} \mid i < \lambda \}$ for limit ordinals $\lambda \le \mu$. Now, by construction and the fact that $C$ is closed, $\{ \kappa_{i} \mid i \le \mu \} \subseteq C$ and $\kappa_{\mu}$ has cofinality $\operatorname{cf}(\mu)$. Q.E.D.

(The latter follows from the general fact that given a normal sequence $(\kappa_{i} \mid i < \mu)$ of ordinals, we have $\operatorname{cf}(sup_{i < \mu} \kappa_{i}) = \operatorname{cf}(\mu)$.)